# Use lodash function to determine if one of the element in object fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have an array of object which looks like ,

```
const test = [{"id": "1", "status": "progress"},{"id": "1", "status": "book"},{"id": "1", "status": "completed"}, {"id": "1", "status": "done"}]
```

Here I want to get a that if any of the object from the given array has value other than `"progress"` and `"book"` it should return false, or else should return true.

I used the following way

```
const issome = _.some(test, item => !_.includes(["progress", "book"], item.status))
```

How to implement this ?

thanks.

Comment: "Is this right way to do this ?" Does it work for you? :) If not what was the problem?

Comment: This does not work for me.. it returns always true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
_.every(test, item => item.status === "book" || item.status === "progress"))
```

```js
const test = [{"id": "1", "status": "book"},{"id": "1", "status": "book"},{"id": "1", "status": "book"}, {"id": "1", "status": "book"}]

console.log(_.every(test, item => item.status === "book" || item.status === "progress"));

const test1 = [{"id": "1", "status": "xxxxx"},{"id": "1", "status": "book"},{"id": "1", "status": "book"}, {"id": "1", "status": "book"}]

console.log(_.every(test1, item => item.status === "book" || item.status === "progress"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's works it's the right way. You have `!` in wrong place.
What you are doing now is **checking if there is some item that has success not equal to process or book**.
What I would recommend is not using lodash if it's not neccessary.
You could use JavaScript native [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/some) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/includes)

```
const issome = !test.some(item => ['book', 'progress'].includes(item.status))
```

Comment: actully, it does not work and how do I do in the lodsh way

Answer (score 0):

> if any of the object from the given array has value other than
> "progress" and "book" it should return false, or else should return
> true

```
const test = [{"id": "1", "status": "progress"},{"id": "1", "status": "book"},{"id": "1", "status": "completed"}, {"id": "1", "status": "done"}]
const issome = _.every(test, item => _.includes(["progress", "book"], item.status))

//issome===false because there are values with status other than "book" or "progress"


const test = [{"id": "1", "status": "progress"},{"id": "1", "status": "book"}]
const issome = _.every(test, item => _.includes(["progress", "book"], item.status))

//issome===true because there are values with status "book" or "progress" only
```